# A word for materials everything is made of

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

If I'm talking about stuff things are made of (e.g. the brick is made of wood) or about materials as such not concrete objects (e.g. butter as material not as a pack of butter or the matter "inside" stones) is "**substance**" the most general term? I mean both artificial and natural objects.

Comment: You may be looking for _components_ here. E.g., _The components of concrete are water, aggregate, and Portland cement._

Comment: After more thought: perhaps _constituents_ is the word you need. I admit that you threw me with the "bricks made of wood," though.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I can't call things that look like briks but are not briks "briks"? I mean in the shape of briks.

Comment: Oh! In English, without other context, a _brick_ is a rectangular block made of baked clay. We would say _**block** of wood_ to describe what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for *matter*? It's pretty general.

> [matter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matter)
>
> 2. **a** :  the substance of which a physical object is composed

Comment: Now, when you asked, I feel like probably I was looking for this one. :) Thanks. But what is the difference in meaning with the substance?

Comment: I think the answer lies in their scientific meanings. I can't remember, but I think everything physical is made of matter. In plain English, it sounds strange to say "everything is made of substance" (at least to me it sounds strange).